# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs Using foreach On Opencart

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, opencart, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want change tabs on opencart (admin view) with twitter bootstrap 3.0, the code following :

[catalog_form.tpl](https://github.com/classmild/testshop/blob/master/admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.tpl#L17)

```
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab-general" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_general; ?></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#tab-data" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_data; ?></a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#tab-design" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab-general" class="tab-pane fade active in"> 

  <ul id="languages" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
         <li class="<?php if ($i == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>"> 
            <a href="#language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /> <?php echo $language['name']; ?></a>
        </li>
      <?php $i++; } ?>
  </ul>
  <div id="Mylanguages" class="tab-content">
    <?php $a = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
      <div id="language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="tab-pane fade <?php if ($a == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?> in">
      <?php echo $language['language_content']; ?>
      </div>
    <?php $a++; } ?> 
  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="tab-data" class="tab-pane fade">
   ...
  </div>
  <div id="tab-design" class="tab-pane fade">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent tabs (tab-general, tab-data, tab-design) without foreach work perfectly

**First reload, language 1** is active tab

[image]

**When click language 2's tab**

- link `#language2` tag have `selected` class
- `div` tag with id `language2` have display block but not have `active` class
- language 1 `li` still have `active` class but language 2 `li`  have not `active` class.

[image]

When I try copy html (via inspect element) and make on jsfiddle (modify content not html tag) it's works perfectly. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drjWD/1/)

Comment: Your php codes work for me with Bootstrap 3. When i click 2nd tab, it has class `active`

Comment: Remember that you have `ul#languages` and `div#languages`, they might conflict each other (no two elements in HTML should have the same ID). One with `.nav.nav-tabs` and another as `.tab-content`

Comment: @JofryHS : sorry my mistake, I have change it but still not work

Comment: @Bora at jsfiddle code work (using html copy via inspect element) and on my apps without foreach but on my apps not work with foreach.

Comment: @KapanjadiMomod I tried with your php codes and worked

Comment: @Bora : I'm using opencart, I have updated my questions. Can you check and test my apps? here [my apps repository](https://github.com/classmild/testshop)

Comment: @GeekToL Installed your app.Can you give me your page link(local) ?

Comment: @GeekToL Which page should I check?

Comment: When there will be some error in your javascript code clicking the tab will reload the page in stead of activate the second tab by javascript. The reload will set the first tab active again. This will explain why your fiddle works and your local php template not.

Comment: @devo : this url `http://localhost/testshop/admin/index.php?route=catalog/category/insert&token=xxxxx` thanks

Comment: @BassJobsen I think twitter bootstrap tabs when clicking tab not reload the page, it's just reload content on tab.

Comment: yes, you're right it shouldn't reload, but it will do when your Javascript breaks on errors. This errors also could else where in your code. This will explain why the active tab is not set exactly.

Comment: @BassJobsen when I check the console no error message, bora have tired my php code and it's work (not using opencart). I think this issue on opencart, really confuse. I have tired make a question at opencart forum but there has been no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Just remove default jquery tabs on opencart

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#tabs a').tabs(); 
$('#languages a').tabs();
//--></script>
```

This script will you see on template file using language tabs `admin/view/template/xxx/xxxx_form.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend i hope you don't get upset with mentioning some basics in php , this answer might view by others, i have seen you other answers and i know you are geek ;) ...

$languages is an array, and controllers might send it to your web page with the same order
and the order will not change  the `var_dump($languages);` of the array is something like this:

```
    array(2) {
      ["en"]=&gt;
      array(9) {
        ["language_id"]=&gt;
        string(1) "3"
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(7) "English"
        ["code"]=&gt;
        string(2) "en"
        ["locale"]=&gt;
        string(31) "en_US.UTF-8,en_US,en-gb,english"
        ["image"]=&gt;
        string(6) "en.png"
        ["directory"]=&gt;
        string(7) "english"
        ["filename"]=&gt;
        string(7) "english"
        ["sort_order"]=&gt;
        string(1) "0"
        ["status"]=&gt;
        string(1) "1"
      }
      ["fr"]=&gt;
      array(9) {
        ["language_id"]=&gt;
        string(1) "2"
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(10) "..."
        ["code"]=&gt;
        string(2) "..."
        ["locale"]=&gt;
        string(31) "..."
        ["image"]=&gt;
        string(6) "..."
        ["directory"]=&gt;
        string(7) "...."
        ["filename"]=&gt;
        string(7) "..."
        ["sort_order"]=&gt;
        string(1) "1"
        ["status"]=&gt;
        string(1) "1"
      }

}
```

on the other hand, when you click on tabs , the page wouldn't refresh and somehow its not AJAX , so we  shouldn't  changing our php code.

> i think you have changed a little in your php code ,
>   maybe this code i have written here work for you ...

```
<?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
    <li><a href="#language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><i class="lang-<?php echo str_replace('.png','', $language['image']); ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>"></i> <?php echo $language['name']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

hope the bests , my dear opencarter ... 
;)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but didn't change and still not work. I have solved my problem.